# What does "process changes its effective UID or GID" mean in the cgrulesengd man page?

Tags: linux, cgroups

I am planning to user cgrules.config to move processes stared by a user to my cgroup. The man page(https://linux.die.net/man/8/cgrulesengd) of cgrulesengd says that any time a process changes its effective UID or GID it is invoked and moves the process based on the config. But what does the statement "process changes its effective UID or GID" exactly mean. Does it include all the scenarios when a process is started i.e. any new process will be moved based on config.

I have been playing with some configs and found out that yes, new processes do get moved but want to make sure as it is not clear from the documentation.